# multidimensional array of zeros

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to code for a 4x4 table filled with zeros but the output comes out as a list of 16 zeros instead and I'm not sure why. I have to code for a robotGame where the robot moves on a grid of zeros; the robot moving is represented by a 1. But i still can't get a table of zeros to print out, it just prints a list of zeros.

```
package robotGame;

public class RobotGame {

    static int gridSize = 4;
    static char[][] grid = new char[gridSize][gridSize];
    static int numOfSteps;
    static Robot robot1 = new Robot("Wally", 5);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initGrid();
        printGrid();
    }

    public static void initGrid(){
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
                grid[i][j] = (char) ('0');
    }

    public static void printGrid() {
        for (int row = 0;row < gridSize; row ++)
            for (int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++)
                System.out.println (grid[row][col]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `println` prints its input string, then a new line. So you have a new line at every evaluation...

You need to use `System.out.print(cell)` for each value of a line, then `System.out.println()` once between lines.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
for (int row = 0;row < gridSize; row ++)
    for (int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++)
        System.out.println (grid[row][col]);
}
```

Should be changed to

```
for (int row = 0;row < gridSize; row ++)
    for (int col = 0; col < gridSize; col++){
        System.out.print (grid[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

### Output

```
0000
0000
0000
0000
```

---

Print 4 zeros and then go to the nextline.